# Changing the default object embed sizes?

Tags: php, embed

I was using the code below to set the default size for embeded objects in my posts. It worked before for me but now it no longer works.

```
 add_filter( 'embed_defaults', 'bigger_embed_size' );

 function bigger_embed_size()
 { 
 return array( 'width' => 935, 'height' => 525 );
 }
```

I also used this css so that when viewed from mobile devices the width of the embeded object would be so tall.

```
embed,
iframe,
object,
script,
video {
margin-bottom: 1.6em;
max-width: 100% !important;
vertical-align: middle !important;
min-height:250px;
}
```

None of these options are working anymore does anyone have a solution.

Comment: Have you added any plugins that might override them? Perhaps upping the priority might help. `add_filter( 'embed_defaults', 'bigger_embed_size', 100 );`

Comment: I don't think i've added any plugin that would effect media sizes

Comment: and upping the priority didn't help :(

Comment: silly question, but sometimes its those that answer the problem, is the `add_filter` actually running? try `die('HERE')` right before it and ensure that "HERE" is the only thing printed to the screen. Otherwise try looking for PHP errors.

Comment: is it public so we can see the issue?

Comment: Is what public @BenCasey

Comment: @TerrelAnderson Im asking if your website is public.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I crafted to override the defaults, I set a default media width, choose an aspect ratio (16:9) and then replace the video shortcode output.

```
$defaultMediaWidth = 960;

if ( ! isset( $content_width ) ) {
  $content_width = $defaultMediaWidth;
}
add_filter( 'embed_defaults', 'bigger_embed_size');

function bigger_embed_size()
{
  global $content_width;
  $width = $content_width;
  // aspect ratio 16:9
  $r1 = 16;
  $r2 = 9;
  $r = $width / $r1;
  $height = $r * $r2;

  return array( 'width' => $width, 'height' => $height );
}

function EMP_video_shortcode_override(
  $output = '',
  $atts = [],
  $video = '',
  $post_id = 0,
  $library = ''
){
  $defaults = wp_embed_defaults();
  $searchfor = [
    'width="' . $atts['width'] . '"',
    'width: ' . $atts['width'] . 'px;',
    'height="' . $atts['height'] . '"'
  ];
  $replaceto = [
    'width="' . $defaults['width'] . '"',
    'width:' . $defaults['width'] . 'px;',
    'height="' . $defaults['height'] . '"'
  ];
  return str_ireplace( $searchfor, $replaceto, $output );
}
add_filter('wp_video_shortcode', 'EMP_video_shortcode_override', 10 , 5);
```